# binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n \left(\dfrac{1}{x} -1\right)^m$

Tags: generating-functions

Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers with $n \gt m$. Can you show that the constant term of 
$${(1+x)^n}\left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right)^m$$ is not equal to zero?

Comment: I tried $\LaTeX$-ifying your equation; please check that I did this correctly (I did not know if you meant $(\frac{1}{x}-1)^m$ or $(\frac{1}{x-1})^m$, but I'm guessing the former).

Comment: Thanks for the editing! Your writing is correct.

Comment: You can expand : 
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^n \left( \frac 1x - 1 \right)^m & = \left( \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni x^i\right) \left( \sum_{j=0}^m \binom mj x^{-j} (-1)^{m-j}\right) \\
& = \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m \binom ni \binom mj x^{i-j} (-1)^{m-j} \\
\end{align*}
so that the constant term is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{m}  \binom nj \binom mj (-1)^{m-j}
$$
(let $i=j$ to find the possible coefficients that belong to this sum).

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also the case when n=m. If n is odd, it is zero. But for even n it is ((-1)^(n/2))(n choose n/2)

Comment: For the cases $n=m+k$, where $ k=1,2,3,4 $, it is done.

Comment: Please either make @PatrickDaSilva rewrite his comment as an answer or do it yourself and accept it to close the question.